# Combobox SelectedItem DataBinding NullReference Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am a bit frustrated with combobox right now and am hoping someone has an answer for my question. The problem is with SelectedItem.  When i run my app in debugger it will throw a null reference exception if I enter text into the ComboBox that matchs an Item(ie.. a, b, or c) in Items, and then delete the text. If i enter text into the ComboBox and that does not match and Item(ie.. z) in Items and then delete the text, it does not crash. This behavior only happens within the debugger.  If I run the application outside I do not crash. I'm using the mvvmlight tookit however i'm not thinking it has anything to do with that.  My code is below

**View:**

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Item,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**Model:**

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**VM:**

```
public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>
          {
            new Item {Name="a", Id=0},
            new Item {Name="b", Id=1},
            new Item {Name="c", Id=2},
          };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Items" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string ItemsPropertyName = "Items";

    private List<Item> _items;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the Items property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public List<Item> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(ItemsPropertyName, ref _items, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Item" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string ItemPropertyName = "Item";

    private Item _item;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the Item property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public Item Item
    {
        get
        {
            return _item;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(ItemPropertyName, ref _item, value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you explain a little more what you're referring to when you say you are entering and deleting items? Is this in the UI? Or in code? or...?

Comment: When i run the app in debugger, the combobox property IsEditable="True".  Therefore i can add and delete text from the combobox.  Sorry i will edit to make that clear.

Comment: At first sight your code looks perfect and should run in one shot. So I tried it and it worked as expected. So the code you provided has no problem.

Comment: As much as i would love to believe that Nitesh, did you try running it from the debugger?   I'm using VS2012 at home and VS2010 at work and both do the exact same thing.  If i start without debugging it works.  If i start with debugging it crashes.  Type "a" then backspace and you will get a null reference exception.

Comment: Please post the full exception with all stack traces.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is a bug in .NET Framework 4 (and .NET 4.5, **not in .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5**).

Method `PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.DetermineWhetherDBNullIsValid(object item)` is causing the issue.

Looked with .NET Reflector, its code looks like this:

```
private bool DetermineWhetherDBNullIsValid(object item)
{
    PropertyInfo info;
    PropertyDescriptor descriptor;
    DependencyProperty property;
    DynamicPropertyAccessor accessor;
    this.SetPropertyInfo(this._arySVS[this.Length - 1].info, out info, out descriptor, out property, out accessor);
    string columnName = (descriptor != null) ? descriptor.Name : ((info != null) ? info.Name : null);
    object arg = ((columnName == "Item") && (info != null)) ? this._arySVS[this.Length - 1].args[0] : null;
    return SystemDataHelper.DetermineWhetherDBNullIsValid(item, columnName, arg);
}
```

Issue is in the following line:

```
object arg = ((columnName == "Item") && (info != null)) ? this._arySVS[this.Length - 1].args[0] : null;
```

Code assumes that if `columnName` is `"Item"`, then property is indexer and tries to access its first argument via `args[0]` and this is where `NullReferenceException` occurs because `args` is `null` since property is not indexer. It just happens to be named `"Item"`.

.NET implementers should have used [PropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getindexparameters.aspx) on `info` and if returned array doesn't contain zero elements, make certain assumption that property is indexer. Or use [Binding.IndexerName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.indexername.aspx) for checking (Binding.IndexerName has value `"Item[]"`).

Why issue arises only in Visual Studio debugger is much more subtle and it is hidden in following method:
**PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.DetermineWhetherDBNullIsValid()**.

Here is a disassembled code:

```
private void DetermineWhetherDBNullIsValid()
{
    bool flag = false;
    object item = this.GetItem(this.Length - 1);
    if ((item != null) && AssemblyHelper.IsLoaded(UncommonAssembly.System_Data))
    {
        flag = this.DetermineWhetherDBNullIsValid(item);
    }
    this._isDBNullValidForUpdate = new bool?(flag);
}
```

Since `item` variable won't be null (it is actually an instance of [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx) which holds `MainViewModel` instance), only condition for which failing method `DetermineWhetherDBNullIsValid(item)` is called is if System.Data.dll assembly is loaded, which is checked with `AssemblyHelper.IsLoaded(UncommonAssembly.System_Data)`.

Visual Studio debugger will always load System.Data.dll because project is referencing it, although it is not using it.
Outside Visual Studio debugger, System.Data.dll gets loaded only if used, which is never, and that is why application doesn't fail outside Visual Studio.

You have following options to get rid of this issue:

1. Rename property which is bound to `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to some name other than `"Item"` so that buggy .NET implementation doesn't assume anymore that property is indexer.
2. Remove System.Data.dll from project references so it doesn't get loaded even in Visual Studio debugger.

I find option 2 more fragile, since situation may arise that System.Data.dll must be loaded, either directly by your application or indirectly by some other loaded assembly.

So I would go with option 1.

Comment: Confirming that both options are works as described - tested on VS2012 targeting .NET 4.5. Good job @Stipo and thanks for sharing! The moral of this story - **never** names any of your view-model's property as "**Item**" :)

Comment: Oh my god...you saved my night!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, You saved my life!

Comment: This is one of the most odd .NET bugs that I've ever experienced. Thank you so much for your answer because I was at a loss.

Answer (score 4):

I'm able to reproduce this on my side. Add this to your combobox code:

```
IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
```

Anyways, who else is interested in this problem, the stacktrace for this exception is as follows

> PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.DetermineWhetherDBNullIsValid(object item) + 0xc7 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.DetermineWhetherDBNullIsValid() + 0x64 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.IsDBNullValidForUpdate.get() + 0x2e bytes 
>       PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.IsDBNullValidForUpdate.get() + 0xa bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertProposedValue(object value) + 0x177 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.UpdateValue() + 0x92 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateOverride() + 0x3d bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Update() + 0x20 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.ProcessDirty() + 0x2f bytes 
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Dirty() + 0x40 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value) + 0x24 bytes
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType, bool isInternal) + 0x3c4 bytes
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetCurrentValueInternal(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value) + 0x35 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.UpdatePublicSelectionProperties() + 0x13f bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End() + 0x80 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.SelectJustThisItem(System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.ItemInfo info, bool assumeInItemsCollection) + 0x145 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelectedIndexChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) + 0xd9 bytes
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) + 0x4d bytes 
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) + 0x50 bytes
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) + 0x3b bytes
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType) + 0x757 bytes
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType, bool isInternal) + 0x2ea bytes
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetCurrentValueInternal(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value) + 0x35 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.TextUpdated(string newText, bool textBoxUpdated) + 0x26e bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.OnEditableTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e) + 0x2e bytes 
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate genericHandler, object genericTarget) + 0x2c bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target) + 0x33 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) + 0x44 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised) + 0x1a8 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args) + 0x73 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) + 0x29 bytes 
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase.OnTextChanged(System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e) + 0x5 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase.OnTextContainerChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Documents.TextContainerChangedEventArgs e) + 0xe0 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.OnTextContainerChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Documents.TextContainerChangedEventArgs e) + 0x17d bytes 
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Documents.TextContainer.EndChange(bool skipEvents) + 0xb6 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Documents.TextContainer.System.Windows.Documents.ITextContainer.EndChange(bool skipEvents) + 0xb bytes 
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Documents.TextRangeBase.EndChange(System.Windows.Documents.ITextRange thisRange, bool disableScroll, bool skipEvents) + 0x59 bytes 
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Documents.TextRange.System.Windows.Documents.ITextRange.EndChange(bool disableScroll, bool skipEvents) + 0x11 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Documents.TextRange.ChangeBlock.System.IDisposable.Dispose() + 0x15 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Documents.TextEditorTyping.OnDelete(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args) + 0x1a7 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnExecuted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) + 0x65 bytes 
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.ExecuteCommandBinding(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e, System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding commandBinding) + 0x92 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(System.Windows.Input.CommandBindingCollection commandBindings, object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e, System.Windows.Input.ICommand command, bool execute) + 0x105 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e, System.Windows.Input.ICommand command, bool execute) + 0x15e bytes 
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnExecuted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) + 0x25 bytes 
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.OnExecutedThunk(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) + 0x46 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate genericHandler, object target) + 0x3c bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target) + 0x33 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) + 0x44 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised) + 0x1a8 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args) + 0x73 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args) + 0x3d bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool trusted) + 0x40 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteImpl(object parameter, System.Windows.IInputElement target, bool userInitiated) + 0x105 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteCore(object parameter, System.Windows.IInputElement target, bool userInitiated) + 0x59 bytes 
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.TranslateInput(System.Windows.IInputElement targetElement, System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs inputEventArgs) + 0x59b bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.OnKeyDownThunk(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e) + 0x52 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate genericHandler, object genericTarget) + 0x2c bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target) + 0x33 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) + 0x44 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised) + 0x1a8 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args) + 0x73 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args) + 0x3d bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool trusted) + 0x40 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() + 0x1f8 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs input) + 0x45 bytes 
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport inputReport) + 0x62 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ReportInput(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.Windows.Input.InputMode mode, int timestamp, System.Windows.Input.RawKeyboardActions actions, int scanCode, bool isExtendedKey, bool isSystemKey, int virtualKey) + 0xee bytes 
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ProcessKeyAction(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, ref bool handled) + 0xac bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.CriticalTranslateAccelerator(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys modifiers) + 0x94 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage(object param) + 0x12c bytes
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) + 0x56 bytes 
>       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) + 0x3a bytes
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs) + 0x10e bytes 
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.Delegate method, object arg) + 0x3e bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessageThunk(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, ref bool handled) + 0x93 bytes
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.WeakEventPreprocessMessage.OnPreprocessMessage(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, ref bool handled) + 0x33 bytes
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcherThread.RaiseThreadMessage(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg) + 0x3c bytes
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) + 0x9a bytes
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) + 0x49 bytes
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run() + 0x4b bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore) + 0x17 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window) + 0x6f bytes 
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window window) + 0x26 bytes 
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run() + 0x1b bytes 
>       WpfApplication1.exe!WpfApplication1.App.Main() + 0x59 bytes C#
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) + 0x6b bytes
>       Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x27 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state) + 0x6f bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0xa7 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x16 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x41 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44 bytes
>       [Native to Managed Transition]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this.  Setting this to False does stop the crash, However, this also requires you to select an Item from the ComboBox to update SelectedItem Binding instead of just being able to type it in.  Like i said though, if you run this without the debugger everything seem to work at expected.  Been scathing my head at this behavior, hoping someone can give me the why on this.

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

1. Write a converter

   ```
   public class NullToItemConverter : IValueConverter
   {
       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
       {
           return value;
       }

       public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
       {
           if (value == null)
               return new Item();
           else
               return value;
       }
   }
   ```
2. in XAML

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
       <local:NullToItemConverter x:Key="nullToItemConverter"/>
   </Window.Resources
   ```

   ...

   ```
   <ComboBox IsEditable="True"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Name"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Item, Mode=TwoWay , Converter={StaticResource nullToItemConverter}}"/>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this.  I understand this will stop the crash.  However, this leaves Item in your viewmodel as a new Item.  There is no reason I can see that Item should not be able to be set to null.  Like I said above, if you run this without debugging you will not experience the crash.  I'm interested in the why this is happening, not really the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by making the access modifiers **public** so that it can be binded in ***two-way***.